# C# Convert dynamic object to interface

Tags: c#, interface

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        string GetMethod();
    }
    public class MyClass : IMyInterface
    {
       public string GetMethod()
       {}
    }
}
```

//Main Program

```
var ruleClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "MyNameSpace.MyClass"); 
if( ruleClass != null)
{
   IMyInterface myClass = (IMyInterface)ruleClass;
   //throws exception. 
}
```

How can I convert `ruleClass` to `IMyInterface` type so that I can call specific methods in it?

Comment: I don't get a null value of `myClass` at all - I get an exception when you try to cast...

Comment: Yes. It throws an exception. UnWrap method did worked for me.

Comment: Right - please be more careful when describing what you've observed in future questions.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Unwrap` method.

```
IMyInterface myClass = (IMyInterface)ruleClass.Unwrap();
```

You can create it directly too

```
var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass)) as MyClass;
```

Comment: This is the right way to fix it. `CreateInstance` in this case returns a `ObjectHandle`, not a `MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var ruleClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
if (ruleClass != null)
{
    var myClass = (IMyInterface)ruleClass;
    myClass.GetMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option as well

```
var typ = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass", true);
var ruleClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
        if (ruleClass != null)
        {
            IMyInterface myClass = (IMyInterface)ruleClass;
            //myClass is NULL. 
        }`
```