# Entity Framework - Select() an Interface

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table with 70 columns (strings, ints, some dates) and there are times I need just 4 or 9 of the columns.

Is there a way to do something like `Select(row => row as IMySubset)`?

And if not (I assume not as I couldn't find anything), how do I select just 9 columns, and have them populate a defined class (not a dynamic type)?

And if that can't be done, [is dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650939/select-only-specific-columns-from-included-table-in-entity-framework-core) the only way to go? [They can be cast to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780396/c-sharp-convert-dynamic-object-to-interface) so that works. But it will be much cleaner if there's a way to `Select( IMyInterface)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I select just 9 columns, and have them populate a defined class (not a dynamic type)?

Just project the query results into a new instance of your target type.

```
from e in MyTable
select new MySubset() {A=e.A, B=e.B,...}
```

Comment: thank you very much - that's clean (I like it).